# Need to restart Eclipse in order to get form elements to show up

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I had developed a small JSF 2.2 web app which contains some input text fields. Right now the project is working fine, but the problem is when I execute my program on GlassFish 4.0 for the second time some of the form elements are not showing-up. Whenever I want to execute my program for second time I need to restart the eclipse and then execute, then only all the form elements are showing-up. I am unable to understand where the problem is occurring and even the error-log is clear.

The form elements after the Date-in are not showing-up when I execute the program for the second time. Managed bean has getters-Setters and a method to insert the inputs of the form to the database. I am unable to find what mistake I made in the code, can it be a problem with GlassFish?

XHTML code:

```
    <!--Name -->
    <h:outputLabel for="fnm" value="First Name:*" style="font-weight:bold" />
</div>
<p:inputText id="fnm" value="#{userData.fnm}"
    validatorMessage="First Name cannot be left blank and must be greater than 3 characters">
    <f:validateLength minimum="4" />
    <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="firstname" event="blur" process="@this" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="fnm" id="firstname" display="icon,text" />

<!-- Time and Date In of the Visitor -->
<p:calendar id="datein" readonlyInput="true" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{userData.datein}"
    required="true" mindate="today">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
<script>
    today = Date();
</script>
<p:calendar id="timein" readonlyInput="true" value="#{userData.timein}" required="true"
    pattern="HH:mm a" timeOnly="true" mintime="time" />

<!-- Expected Time and Date out -->
<p:calendar id="edateout" readonlyInput="true" value="#{userData.edateout}" required="true"
    mindate="today" />
<p:calendar id="etimeout" readonlyInput="true" value="#{userData.etimeout}" pattern="HH:mm a"
    timeOnly="true" />

<!-- Vehicle Category -->
<p:selectOneMenu id="vcat" value="#{userData.vcat}" editable="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Truck" itemValue="truck" noSelectionOption="true" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userData.add}" align="center" ajax="false" />
```

Comment: Post relevant code, of the page and managed bean used

Comment: I had posted the relevent code of my webapp @Predrag Maric

Comment: Please see [ask] and the [jsf info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) on how to create a relevant (mcve) example

Comment: Hi- i removed the calendar component from the form and executed, now all the form elements are rendering. I wonder if there are any bugs in prime-faces calendar

Comment: You placed your <script>today = Date();</script> first after the <p:calendar id="datein"..., where it is used. Try to move your script above p:calendar. I suggest also to take a look on a javascript console (for example, FireBug plugin in FireFox), you may get useful error messages there.

Comment: Even after removing the script, im facing the same issue, and then later i removed all the calendar components from the form and then executed the program. Now, all the form elements are rendering,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with the date values as there are previous values of submitted form ,the calendar element of primefaces will not be able to render. To make calendar elements render properly you have to clear the older values one way of doing this is you can nullify your calendar values,once the values gets submitted into your database table, but be sure that you will not be using the variables anymore, once you nullify your values you will not be able to use them at any point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, i cleared the form after submitting the values and its working excellent now. The was form was not showing-up some fields because of the Session data of the form  which i had submitted before.